# Logical replication delay postgresql

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I would like to ask whether logical replication have delay feature to delay the replication to the slave? If yes, how would I be able to do so? Thank you in advance.
I have a postgresql database and I would like to replicate my db to another server

I am using logical replication right now

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.

Comment: does streaming replication have delay feature?

Comment: Physical streaming replication has [`recovery_min_apply_delay`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/standby-settings.html#RECOVERY-MIN-APPLY-DELAY), but I don't think there is anything like that for logical replication.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

For Logical Replication delay, you can use the delay option but you have to switch to PGLogical Extention (which is not native like Logical Replication) but is has same architecture with slight different scripts.

Documentation:

> https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources-old/pglogical/pglogical-docs/

Parameter:

```
apply_delay
```

Note that PGLogical is an older extension with more capabilities than Logical Replication, but not sure if is well maintained or adding features.